# Make a LINQ query on object implementing interface

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

See the code below. I'd like do some check on some properties (on IsActive for example). Could you tell me how do this in my case how implement this in the GetList() ?

Thanks,

```
   public interface ILookup
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string FR { get; set; }
        string NL { get; set; }
        string EN { get; set; }
        bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }

    public class LookupA : ILookup
    {

    }
    public class LookupB : ILookup
    {

    }

    public interface ILookupRepository<T>
    {
        IList<T> GetList();
    }


    public class LookupRepository<T> : ILookupRepository<T>
    {
        public IList<T> GetList()
        {
            List<T> list = Session.Query<T>().ToList<T>();
            return list;
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know `T` will be of type `ILookup` you need to put a constraint on it like such:

```
public interface ILookup
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string FR { get; set; }
    string NL { get; set; }
    string EN { get; set; }
    bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class LookupA : ILookup
{

}
public class LookupB : ILookup
{

}

public interface ILookupRepository<T>
{
    IList<T> GetList();
}


public class LookupRepository<T> : ILookupRepository<T> where T : ILookup
{
    public IList<T> GetList()
    {
        List<T> list = Session.Query<T>().Where(y => y.IsActive).ToList<T>();
        return list;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Darn, beat me by seconds ;p Aside: in my code I also had `where T : ILookup` on `ILookupRepository<T>`, since it sounds like it is always used with `ILookup` - maybe one for the OP to ponder...

Comment: I had constraint on `ILookupRepository` also but removed it. The reason for this is that I don't see a reason to constrain `ILookupRepository` to just one type, even though the name of the `interface` suggest so. I wouldn't constrain myself more than necessary.

Comment: Imagine, I'd like add as parameter the field name I want the value back, example : GetById(myIdValue, thefield), thefield has the value EN, FR or NL

Comment: If you don't have that many parameters I would sort of hard code it for performance. But if you have more than EN, FR and NL I would use reflection. Is your string some kind of lookup for translations? If that is the case I would use some kind of dictionary instead of having one variable per language.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to leverage [Generic Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to help you out.

First, change your interface definition:

```
public interface ILookupRepository<T> where T : ILookup
//                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Second, change your class definition to match the constraints:

```
public class LookupRepository<T> : ILookupRepository<T> where T : ILookup
//                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The constraint will require the generic type parameter to implement `ILookup`. This will let you use the interface members in your `GetList` method.

Comment: He doesn't need the constraint on `ILookupRepository` to get his thing working. Read my comment on my answer why I think that is not necessary.